# Python locust not working in AWS instances

Tags: python, locust

I am trying to use locust in ec2 instance for load testing of my project. So, I have installed locust using this command:

```
python -m pip install locustio
```

I got this below response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: locust in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: locustio in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from locust) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack>=0.4.2 in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (0.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent>=1.2.2 in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (1.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=16.0.2 in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (17.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask>=0.10.1 in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from locustio->locust) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio->locust) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio->locust) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio->locust) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio->locust) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.14; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent>=1.2.2->locustio->locust) (0.4.15)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio->locust) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio->locust) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio->locust) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio->locust) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask>=0.10.1->locustio->locust) (1.0)
```

I was thinking, locust is already installed. But when I execute my python script to start the server, it says below:

```
bash: locust: command not found
```

Can anyone please help me understand what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you execute your script? Please post a [mcve] as well.

Comment: @ForceBru : i did like this : locust -f tests/locustfile.py

Comment: @AgniswarBakshi check the installation folder of the locust. I run it something in this picture https://twitter.com/gunesmes/status/639877497476259840 master and slave configuration

Comment: can you check using below commands ? It may be path issue as well.

```which locust```

```whereis locust```

Answer (score 2):

ec2 instances don't necessarily install things in the usual directories.

I'd suggest running a command like:

```
find / -name locust 2>/dev/null
```

This will show you where locust has been installed (possible somewhere like /home/{user}/.local/bin)

Add this to your path (or whatever directory you found in the command above):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/{user}/.local/bin
```

After that your shell should be able to find the command.